# Comment on checkin appears empty or jibberish on TFS Side

Tags: tfs, character-encoding, visual-studio-code, tfvc

VSCODE connected to TFVC. Checkin works but text entered in Message/Comment field in VSCODE, becomes empty or jibberish in TFS changeset comment field. It occurs no matter the language of the text (English, other, combined).

Comment as appears on regular Visual Studio in View History :
[image]

Comment: What language is your computer set to? What collation is the TFS database using? Do you get the same error with changesets created in Visual Studio? What about in the web portal?

Comment: Thank u for your comments.
Windows 7 Enterprise, VSCode 1.16.0, TFSVC Plugin 1.122.0.
In Visual Studio it works fine with mixed content comment in two languages as set in windows 7 system, either mixed languages in same comment or the just the other language (not the english).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

There maybe a check-in comment issue with **VSCode 1.16** such as comment not get passed.

[TFVC Comment Not being passed to tf checkin command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues/312)

Suggest you give a try with  downgrading VS Code Version or use *1.170-insider*

---

To narrow down the issue:

- Suggest you try to use visual studio to check in the same comment of a new changeset.
- Try to use [tf changeset command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/changeset-command) to list the comment info, it
  will shows either it's a server side issue or the gibberish comment also stored
  in TFS database.
- Change your OS system language to English(if not) and try again

Comment: Thank u for your reply.<br/>
- With regular visual studio it works fine e.g. with most uptodate release of visual studio 2017.<br/>
- My OS GUI language is english, though i use two languages for data entry. Tried only english, sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Comment: @moital `sometimes it works and sometimes not` this maybe a cache issue or client issue . Did you have any other machine with VSCode installed, you could give a try with that. If others works perfect, suggest you try to uninstall the TFS source control plug-in or  directly re-installed VSCode.

Comment: It occurs also on another machine with fresh installed VSCODE and TFS source control plugin, but just to note, i'm relating to the VS Team Services extension by microsoft as found on the market here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team not to the TFS plugin which is found on the market here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ivangabriele.vscode-tfs. Is there a recommendation which to use ?

Comment: @moital Suggest you to use microsoft released version, the first one. Just note it's only support on Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 (and later).  There maybe a check-in comment issue with **VSCode 1.16** such as comment not get passed. https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues/312 
You could give a try with  downgrading VS Code Version or use *1.170-insider*.Which may do the trick.

Comment: Thank u, we'll wait for 1.170 LTS to include a solution.